# Using <pre> tags vs 4 space indentation

Tags: discussion, formatting

Which should be used to format a block of text in code (monospace font). I personally believe that manually indenting each line of long console output or a log file can be very slow and repetitive, so those times, I often find myself using `<pre></pre>` tags. I also feel that it's much easier when creating a new line of code, you don't have to put 4 spaces at the start of each line.

So, should `<pre></pre>` tags be used over indentation for code blocks?

Comment: I'm rather curious... is this question in response to [this](http://askubuntu.com/posts/346070/revisions)? I'm just curious how many users actually go back and look at their edits...

Comment: @Seth basically, things like that are what I mean. Also, for the 2nd part, usually, I'd add a comment or an answer as well if I feel I can do that, otherwise an edit is all I can do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Manual pre/code allows you to stick HTML in code. This is both a positive and a negative, depending on what you want to show. If you want to embolden a line, as below:

```
dadasdasd
asdasdasd
asdasdasd
asdasdasd
```

... pre/code makes sense. If you wanted to show the `<strong>` tag in use, it's a problem. You have to manually escape the tags.

I have personally settled on using four-spaces. You can highlight the entire block of code (once you've typed it, or pasted it in) and then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or press the <kbd>`<$>`</kbd> button in the toolbar and it'll do all the indentation for you.

I think that's a lot easier than messing around remembering to escape things.

---

The source of the code sample above:

```
<pre><code>dadasdasd
asdasdasd
as<strong>dasdasd</strong>
asdasdasd</code></pre>
```

Comment: What's the use of putting both `<pre>` and `<code>`? Don't they both do the same thing. Also, thanks for saying that you can highlight it all and press the `<$>` button, didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks Oli for making me realize I have wasted a lot of my time adding in spaces in tons of lines >:)

Comment: @minerz029 It's just more semantically correct for HTML. Technically `<pre>` should mean pre-formatted, `<code>` means it's code. Their CSS definitions here mean `<code>` isn't required inside a `<pre>` to get the right *look*, but it's a bad habit to fall into. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742907/why-does-html5-recommend-putting-the-code-element-inside-pre

Comment: Crtl+K a revelation and a time saver all those hours waisted typing 4 spaces at the start of each line! Thanks for that

Comment: Don't you have a programmer's text editor that can do that for you?

Comment: Thanks for the in-browser hint! (@queueoverflow) I'd previously been using `:%s/^/    /` in vim.