# Please can people format code properly

Tags: discussion

Recently I've seen a lot of code being formatted as quote. This is not how it should be done.

### All code should be formatted with one of two styles.

1. If it is just 1 line, with other text around it, use the ` ` formatting, like this:

   `Hello. This is code` and continued sentence.
2. If it is one line, but on its own, it should have 4 spaces before it:

   ```
   Hello. This is code
   ```

   To save adding the 4 spaces to each line manually, highlight your block of code and then click the <kbd>**{ }**</kbd> button on the editing toolbar or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.
3. If it is multi line, use the 4 spaces before each line:

   ```
   Hello.
   This is code
   ```

   To save adding the 4 spaces to each line manually, highlight your block of code and click the <kbd>**{ }**</kbd> button on the editing toolbar.
4. If it's multi line and in a list, indent the code 8 spaces:

   - Hello
   - This is a list

     ```
     Hello
     This is code.
     ```

### How not to do it.

1. Accent (``` `` ```) formatting on a multi-line code block:

   `Hello.
   This is badly formatted code`
2. Quote format (even if you append the 2 spaces):

   > Hello.
   >   This is badly formatted code
3. 2 line breaks between each line:

   ```
   Hello.

   This is badly formatted code
   ```
4. No formatting. Seriously, this is so hard to read. Compare [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259470/252153) with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259471/252153):

   Hello.
   This is badly formatted code
5. HTML tags (`<code>`)

   `Hello.
   This is badly formatted code`

   HTML tags (`<pre>`). It looks okay, but is less nice to edit.

   ```
   Hello.
   This is badly formatted code
   ```
6. Using speech marks

   "Hello. This is badly formatted code"

### Reminder:

All code should be between ` characters (grave accent, often found below the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key), or have 4 spaces at the start of the question.

```
`Only format inline code with this syntax`
```

```
    Format multiline code with this syntax
```

Comment: Meta notice is nice but how many users do you think will comply :P

Comment: @ThomasW. few :( I'm linking it in the comments whenever I see it.

Comment: I'm not sure about your first rule there. If your code is on its own (eg not inline) it should use the 4-space indentation it's to be formatted as a block. Only use inline code for inline code.

Comment: Why not directly link the markdown instructions: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: @the_Seppi I thought it was a little confusing, and this is specifically to say not to use quote formatting.

Comment: I am missing: "1 long line more than fits on screen

Comment: See also http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13592/code-formatting-backticks-or-four-spaces

Comment: You know you can select a block of code / text and use the formatting buttons at the top ?

Comment: On the editor, highlight the entire code excerpt you want to format and click the button marked `{}`.  If it's a multi-line excerpt this will automatically add the four spaces at the start of every line for you.  MUCH more convenient than adding the spaces yourself, if your code excerpt is more than a couple of lines.

Comment: About the grave accents, use the four spaces in front of the line **if** grave accents are part of your code.  I really do like what you wrote here, and I learned something new today!  :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  There are a few bugs with your suggestions and the parsing of markdown, however.  For example, try having a four-space-indented block following a list, or vica-versa.

Comment: @ThomasW. (and Tim) probably users that read Meta format it properly anyway...

Comment: @Wilf indeed, that's probably the case.

Comment: When I used askUbuntu for the first few posts I was missing that kind of info. Maybe there is a way to put a link to  that into the profile page of new users?

Comment: @CatMan This information is visible in the sidebar when you ask a question. It is not as clear when you post an answer. Wherever we put the link, 99% of new users won't read it, unfortunately.

Comment: Well. Links are free. Use the at mutliple places may be not a bad thing. However,  if you would format it nicely (like most stickies in forums), put it on the profice page and provide users a functionaliy to let them select "keep" or "remove" the link, I would bet most would select "keep".  People can only ignore what they know about.

Comment: @CatMan Unfortunately links are not free; we would need to ask the development team to automatically add the link to every new profile, and add the keep / delete functionality, for very little gain. They are looking into ways to improve the site but the funds are limited. This issue is very low down (it's easy to edit to fix this). More important issues include new user training "how to ask" and first question filtering.

Comment: @Tim I am not aware about how tight funds are and what needs to decide centralized, etc. However, from App Dev experience I draw the sad insight that more often than not there is stuff put in that ends up rarely used. One of the hardest things is to create a feature planning for first time end users without a microsoft or google budget, I guess. Thats because it is so hard as developer put put on the hat of a beginner user. Since I use AksUbuntu I find that I never used about 90% functionality I suspect behind the profile page, where I believe is quite a chunk of the work.

Answer (score 16):

There is one special case where `<pre>` may be desirable instead of 4 spaces:

```
This is the important part of the program
```

Notice that I can use `<strong></strong>` within the block of code when I use `<pre>`. However, if I try to do that with the 4-space indent, all I get is:

```
This is the <strong>important</strong> part of the program
```

Comment: I would discourage code formatting like this, but yes fair point.

Comment: For [an HTML code block](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7348) use [`<pre><code>` `</code></pre>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11742907), not `<pre>` `</pre>`. [That's what indenting uses](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code): *"Indent four spaces to create an escaped `<pre> <code>` block"* Text just in `<pre>` tags is styled the same as with `<pre><code>` but there are subtle differences. For example [`<pre>` without `<code>` doesn't get syntax highlighting](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17167). Note that HTML tags [differ from indenting in other ways too](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17166).

Answer (score 7):

If you put a code block after a list, the code block isn't formatted properly:

- bullet

  code block

You can resolve this by indenting the code block 8 spaces, which nests it under the bullet:

- bullet

  ```
  code block
  ```

Or put something invisible between them, like an HTML comment `<!-- comment -->` or a Markdown comment `<% comment %>`, which doesn't nest it:

- bullet

```
code block
```