# Please use code fomatting for code, not quotes

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, code

This is some thing I see all the time recently and not just from new users.

Users are using > to format there code and that is just wrong.

Code should be formatted in one of these three ways

Surround the code with ``

`sudo apt install`

Indent by four spaces

```
sudo apt install
```

or use the code button in the editor {}.

This > creates a quote

> sudo apt install

Same as the "" button in the editor.

Quotes are for when you quote a person or page directly and does not stand out as well as the code formatting.

This seems to be coming more common and is being over looked, in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/790932/revisions) a 4k user used > for code and then a moderator edited it and still missed the > on the code.

Please use correct formatting, it wastes users time to have to edit this  kind of thing and may even get you downvoted.

Comment: Is this not a dupe of [Please can people format code properly](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14089) ?

Comment: @terdon Yes, more or less. Honestly I did not even look, I just posted out of the frustration of seeing this all the time.

Comment: Heh, understandable.

Comment: See also: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/lets-agree-on-some-commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines